# Using Cron to make an API call every day on express server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cron

I am trying to use cron in order to fetch some information from an API every day. This app isn't running all the time yet, I need to fetch data and store it on a daily basis. I would like to implement this on the server side. I'm not sure how to go about this. Below is my server.js file.

```
var express = require('express')
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cron = require('node-cron')
// Middleware
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var logger = require('./middleware/logger')
// Routes
var minerRoutes = require('./routes/miners.js')
var logRoutes = require('./routes/logs.js')
// App and Config
var config = require('./config')
var app = express()

cron.schedule("* * * * *", function() {
    console.log("running a task every minute");
})

// Connect to MongoDB
mongo = config.mongodb
mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + mongo.host + ':' + mongo.port + '/' + mongo.db)
var db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'))

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json())
if(config.logging.enabled){
    app.use(logger)
}

// Routes
app.use('/miners', minerRoutes)
app.use('/logs', logRoutes)

// Public
app.use(express.static('public'))

// Launch the server
app.listen(config.express.port, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port: ' + config.express.port)
})
```

And below is my index.js file which is served.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'


// disable the following line for now
//import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Helmet>
            <title>Miner Monitor</title>
        </Helmet>
        <HashRouter>
            <App />
        </HashRouter>
    </div>
    , document.getElementById('root'))
// uncomment to enable progressive web app behaviour
//registerServiceWorker()
```

I'm confused where to implement cron in order to make an API call every day even if the app isn't running. Thank you !

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution Arthur?

Answer (score 3):

You've to implement cron on the server. In your server.js you can add code to call API  like below when you run your app in the server by

```
node server.js
```

you will see log repeatedly like "running a task every minute" and API call will also get triggered.

```
var request = require('request');
cron.schedule("* * * * *", function() {
            // API call goes here
    console.log("running a task every minute");
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
       if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
       }
    })
})
```